# What does the mteTrigger option in snmpd's SNMPDOPTS do?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to determine why a number of sites are recommending the mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf optons below be placed as options in SNMPDOPTS for snmpd's /etc/default/snmpd (Ubuntu).

`SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'`

What is the benefit of adding these options as apposed to leaving them out?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not entirely sure if Stack Overflow is the best place for this question, I'll try to answer it.

First note that the part `-I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf` is one option. The `-I` option specifies which modules should (or should not) be initialized when the agent starts up. The `'-'` before the second part means that the specified modules should *not* be started.

My guess is that `smux` is disabled because it has been deprecated by the AgentX protocol ([source](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/README.smux.html)), and the `mteTrigger` and `mteTriggerConf` modules because they don't work without non-free MIBs ([source](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=428824)).